# How can I add a user-chooser to all system dialogs?

Tags: debian, gnome

Below is an image depicting my problem. The only user that appears to be authorized to make printer changes is root. I have seen, in the past, the exact same dialog that has a user-chooser where users in sudoers get to also perform the operation. This is using gnome-flashback 3.14.1 on debian jessie. I don't have root on this box but I am in sudoers.

I would like to have the user-chooser show up in all unlock dialogs.

[image: Dialog only allows root]